# Generating function - taking derivative on power series

Tags: combinatorics

I'm working on a generating functions problem, but during one of the steps I just don't understand how it works.

The generating functions for $A(x)=\sum_{k\geq1}kx^k$ and $B(x)=\sum_{m\geq2}{m\choose 2}x^m$, but according to the book, taking the derivatives of $\sum_{i\geq0}x^i=\frac1{1-x}$, this implies that:

$$A(x)=\frac x{(1-x)^2}, B(x)=\frac{x^2}{(1-x)^3}$$

Can someone please explain to me how is this possible?

Ty.

Comment: The derivative of $1/(1-x)$ is $1/(1-x)^2$. Then you multiply by $x$ to get $\sum ix^i$ on the left, and $x/(1-x)^2$ on the right.

Comment: Okay, but how is it possible for $B(x)=x^2/(1-x)^3$?

Comment: Differentiate twice, and multiply by $x^2$.

Comment: But when you take the double derivative there's $i(i-1)$ on the LHS and it's $-\frac2{(1-x)^3}$ on the RHS

Comment: @Gerry? Can you please clarify?

Answer (score 1):

$$\sum_0x^m=(1-x)^{-1}$$ $$\sum mx^{m-1}=(1-x)^{-2}$$ $$\sum m(m-1)x^{m-2}=2(1-x)^{-3}$$ $$\sum m(m-1)x^m=2x^2(1-x)^{-3}$$ Now divide both sides by 2 to get $$\sum{m\choose2}x^m={x^2\over(1-x)^3}$$

Answer (score 0):

There is a mistake in your last summation (as it is written) : the result is effectively   1 / (1-x)^2 which properly corresponds to the derivative of the sum you derive.

Comment: Your answer is … less effective than Gerry's comment

Comment: I accept the point !